# BLE Always getting "state = connecting" from CBPeripheral device

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, swift4

I am getting stuck to make the connection between device and iPhone always I got this state even I keep the reference of Peripheral at the file level OR global. :(

> CBPeripheral: 0x1700f7200, identifier =
>   6F44C292-FA88-41B2-9534-F9EFFDC02708, name = (null), state =
>   connecting

I have to transfer data to the device also send some command.

I used the below code in `didDiscover peripheral:`

```
if (peripheral.identifier.uuidString == "6F44C292-FA88-41B2-9534-F9EFFDC02708") {//6F44C292-FA88-41B2-9534-F9EFFDC02708
     connectingPeripheral = peripheral
     connectingPeripheral.delegate = self
     cbManager.connect(connectingPeripheral, options: [CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey:true])
     cbManager.stopScan()
}
```

**OR is there any way to check BLE device is working or not?**

Comment: Do you get a call to the peripheral delegate methods to let you know that the peripheral has connected? Try supplying `nil` for `options`

Comment: Got call `didDiscover peripheral:` only

Comment: I have also tried with option nil but no luck.

Comment: You need to show more code; particularly your `didConnect` delegate function. If you download the Light Blue app from the store, can it connect to your device?

Comment: LIght blue not able to find services but found the device.

Comment: Could it connect to the device? If not then it sounds like you have a device issue.

Comment: hmm device not getting connected.